# How to get notification of change in database

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want that Whenever there is any change in Specific *table* of `database`, I get notification at `run time`, so that I may be able to take action accordingly in my `Java program`.I am using `tomcat` as server. Is `JMS` help me in this case.Kindly guide me if there is any way to do so.

Thanks

Comment: Triggers may helpful to you? Have you tried with that?

Comment: You mean [Triggers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/samples/jdbc/s-TbTrig-java.htm) ?

Comment: According to my requirement I can't use Triggers.Is there any other way to solve it.Thanks

Comment: @user3090158 no, there is no other way of doing this then using Triggers.